# Javascript not populating Perl Form on Dev Server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, perl, windows-server-2008

I am still a newbie to Perl and have run into difficulties.

I have a system here which needs users to be assigned permissions in order for them to run reports.

The system is fully functional on the local test environment hosted on a machine, but once it was uploaded to the Windows Server 2008 for dev, it doesnt seem to populate the assigned reports form anymore.

We use Javascript functions to populate the user dropdown lists and also to populate the available reports which works. When it comes to assigned reports nothing is populating anymore. The exact same code taken from the depository will work on the Local Environment with no problems.

The assigned reports will only populate if we change the directory of the Perl script to point towards the local machine environment, instead of to the Perl script thats on the server.

This is it pointed towards the Server Directory:

```
function ReadUserPermission( iUserID )
{
    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    var szURL;
    var iPermNumber = 0;

    szURL = "/Scripts/Security/ReadPermissions.pl";

    xmlhttp.Open("POST", szURL, false);
    xmlhttp.Send( iUserID );
    var bRetVal = PermissionTab.loadXML( xmlhttp.responseText );
    var rt = xmlhttp.responseText;

    RGCollection = PermissionTab.XMLDocument.selectNodes("//REPORTGROUP");
    for (var i=0; i< RGCollection.length; i++)
    {
        RGXML = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
        RGXML.loadXML( RGCollection.item(i).xml );

        ReportCollection = RGXML.selectNodes( "//REPORTGROUPNAME" );
        szReportGroupName = ReportCollection.item(0).text;

        ReportCollection    = RGXML.selectNodes( "//REPORTGROUPID" );
        iReportGroupID      = ReportCollection.item(0).text;

        ReportCollection = RGXML.selectNodes( "//REPORT" );
        for( var j=0; j < ReportCollection.length; j++ )
        {
            IR = new ActiveXObject( "MSXML2.DOMDocument" );
            IR.loadXML( ReportCollection.item(j).xml );
            IRD = IR.selectNodes( "//REPORTNAME" );      szReportName    = IRD.item(0).text;
            IRD = IR.selectNodes( "//REPORTID" );        iReportID       = IRD.item(0).text;
            IRD = IR.selectNodes( "//PERMISSION" ); bPermission     = IRD.item(0).text;            

            Users[iUserID].Permissions[iPermNumber]                   = new DataClass;
            Users[iUserID].Permissions[iPermNumber].ReportGroupName   = szReportGroupName;
            Users[iUserID].Permissions[iPermNumber].ReportGroupID     = iReportGroupID;
            Users[iUserID].Permissions[iPermNumber].ReportName        = szReportName;
            Users[iUserID].Permissions[iPermNumber].ReportID          = iReportID;
            Users[iUserID].Permissions[iPermNumber].Permission        = bPermission;
            iPermNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

But when the szURL = "//028-07743/Scripts/Security/ReadPermissions.pl" it runs with no problems.

Can anyone advise any help as this has baffled me.

Here is the ReadPermissions.pl script that we think is not running.

```
use CGI qw/:standard *table start_ul :cgi-lib/;
use Win32::ODBC;
require "ServerDetails.cfg";

#Reads Details for Connection from CFG file
sub ReadCfg
{
    my $file = $_[0];

    our $err;

    {   # Put config data into a separate namespace
        package CFG;

        # Process the contents of the config file
        my $rc = do($file);

        # Check for errors
        if ($@) {
            $::err = "ERROR: Failure compiling '$file' - $@";
        } elsif (! defined($rc)) {
            $::err = "ERROR: Failure reading '$file' - $!";
        } elsif (! $rc) {
            $::err = "ERROR: Failure processing '$file'";
        }
    }

    return ($err);
}

# Get our configuration information
if (my $err = ReadCfg('ServerDetails.cfg')) {
    print(STDERR $err, "\n");
    exit(1);
}

$szDataSource = "DSN=$CFG::CFG{'server'}{'DSN'};UID=$CFG::CFG{'server'}{'UID'};PWD=$CFG::CFG{'server'}{'PWD'}";

%PARM = Vars;
$iUser = $PARM{'keywords'};

open TMP, ">dhtml.txt";
$db = OpenConnection( $szDataSource );

$szSQLStatement = "EXEC spGetUserPermissionTabData '$iUser'";

$iNumRecordsRead = ReadData( -dbconnection=>$db, -sqlstatement=>$szSQLStatement, -datahash=>\%UserData );

$szXMLString = "<Permissions>\n";
$szCurrentReportGroupName = "";
foreach $KEY ( sort{ $a <=> $b } keys %UserData )
{
    if( $szCurrentReportGroupName ne $UserData{$KEY}{AppGroupName} )
    {
        if( $szCurrentReportGroupName ne "" )   #Close any previous report groups
        {
            $szXMLString .= "\t</REPORTGROUP>\n";
        }
        $szXMLString .= "\t<REPORTGROUP>\n" .
                "\t\t<REPORTGROUPNAME>$UserData{$KEY}{AppGroupName}</REPORTGROUPNAME>\n" .
                "\t\t<REPORTGROUPID>$UserData{$KEY}{ApplicationGroupID}</REPORTGROUPID>\n";
        $szCurrentReportGroupName = $UserData{$KEY}{AppGroupName};
    }
    $szXMLString .= "\t<REPORT>\n" .
            "\t\t<REPORTNAME>$UserData{$KEY}{AppDisplayName}</REPORTNAME>\n" .
            "\t\t<REPORTID>$UserData{$KEY}{ApplicationID}</REPORTID>\n" .
            "\t\t<PERMISSION>$UserData{$KEY}{PermissionType}</PERMISSION>\n" .
            "\t</REPORT>\n";
}
$szXMLString .= "\t</REPORTGROUP>\n" .
        "</Permissions>";

print TMP "UserID = $szUser\n";
print TMP "XML = $szXMLString\n";
print TMP "Size of XML = " . length( $szXMLString ) . "\n";
close $TMP;

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "$szXMLString";


sub OpenConnection()
{
    my( $szDSN ) = @_;
    my $db = new Win32::ODBC( $szDSN );

    if( !defined $db )
    {
        my $szLocalTime = localtime();

        $szHTMLString = header;
        $szHTMLString .= "Error creating ODBC connection\n";
        $szHTMLString .= "<BR>Time: $szLocalTime\n";
        $szHTMLString .= end_html();

        print $szHTMLString;

        return NULL;
    }
    return $db;
}

sub ReadData()
{
    my ( %fnArgs ) = @_;
    my $szSQLStatement  = $fnArgs{-sqlstatement};
    my $cDBConnection   = $fnArgs{-dbconnection};
    local( *DataHash )  = $fnArgs{-datahash};

    my $iRowID = 0;
    if ($cDBConnection->Sql($szSQLStatement))
    {
        print "SQL failed. Error: " . $cDBConnection->Error() . "\n";
        $cDBConnection->Close();
        exit;
    }
    while($cDBConnection->FetchRow())
    {
        $DataHash{$iRowID++} = {$cDBConnection->DataHash()};
    }

    return $iRowID;
}

sub XMLizer
{
    local ( *DataHash ) = @_;


    my $szXMLString = "";
    foreach $KEY ( keys %DataHash )
    {
        $szXMLString .= "\t<" . $KEY . ">" . $DataHash{$KEY} . "</" . $KEY . ">\n";
    }

    return $szXMLString;
}
```

It now looks like if we change the SQL statement in the Perl file to `$szSQLStatement = "EXEC spGetUserPermissionTabData 464";` it will populate the assigned window with that specific users reports, even if that user is not select(expected). we now think that maybe the Perl file isnt recieving the iUserID that the Javascript is sending to it

Comment: Can you open the perl script on the server from your browser? What happens? If this is on Windows, which perl distribution are you using? Does the shebang match the path to the interprete?

Comment: Simaque - Nothing appears on the screen but when you view the source the file is being populated with the XML as it should it simply reads: <Permissions> </REPORTGROUP> </Permissions>. the perl version is 5.14.2 on the server and slightly older on the local machine but this shouldnt matter. The path set above is the path set to the file ... the script starts in the scripts folder or do you suggest entering a full path in ? (C:\path\etc)

Comment: That *invalid* XML indicates the Perl script is broken at some level. Do you get better results when executing the script via the "post" method (e.g. from a static html form)? Do you have debug information from the Perl script? Which interfaces are used to connect the script to the browser? Are you just new to Perl or to server-side scripting in general?

Comment: I am new to Perl and Server-side scripting. This system was fully fucntional before being transferred over and has been established 10 years now so i am working with code that was already developed. The Perl script runs fine if we link it locate it from the Local Machine instead of the server both are an exact replica of each other, so the coding is the same. Any ideas into this ? everything on the system works as it should except for this one form window not populating

Comment: the shebang line doesn't matter under windows. I regularly use one with /use/bin/perl

Comment: @justintime: depends on you webserver config. It might matter. Bubba Wilson: Please show the perl script.

Comment: simbabque - it will not allow me to post my perl script for a further 4 hours time due to reputation restrictions. I can however email it or post tomorrow when i return to the office

Comment: you should not post it as an answer. go and [edit] your question. This is a q&a site, not a message board. You can only post answers, and usually only one. All the edits are revisioned, so nothing gets lost (like git or svn).

Comment: I have now posted the script for you.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is a client side scripting language and will not run on a server.

Node.js should be more helpful:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js